# Facebook Graph API: Upload photos into group stopped working

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, oauth

We developed a Mac App, which lets users update their status, post links or upload photos.

When uploading a photo, users can choose the destination of the photo: an album, on a page (user must be admin) or into a group. This really worked fine for month. During the last days posting a photo into a group stopped working.

For uploading we use the Graph API with following URLs:
To users wall: .../me/photos (works)
To a page: .../me/photos (in combination with page access_token: works)
Into an album: ...//photos (works)
Into a group: ...//photos (stopped working!!!)

The error:
Type: OAuthException
Message: #120 - Invalid album id

Someone of you an idea why this stopped working??? Some new permissions? Any hints?

Answer (score -1):

I would ensure DoesCurrentApiDocumentationSayStillPossible() is working as expected.

```
var wasWorking = true;
var stoppedWorking = true;
var documented = DoesCurrentApiDocumentationSayStillPossible("http://developers.facebook.com/docs/");
if(wasWorking && stoppedWorking && documented) {
   LogABugAt("http://developers.facebook.com/bugs");
}
```